# datetime to totalminute in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can I get the total minute for sql datetime?

Let's say:

```
select getdate() from table
```

In this way, I will get everything, but I only want to get total minute. For eg, 
if the time is `07:10:35`, I want `430`.

How to achieve that?

The value from the field is `01-01-2001 07:10:40`
The result I want is `430` ((7*60)+10) only.

Comment: Your question isn't particularly clear.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's a sample:

```
DECLARE @dt datetime 
SET @dt = '01-01-2001 07:10:20'
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @dt), 0), @dt)
```

Comment: returns this error (Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.)

Comment: Oh, sorry; I missed the fact you were on SQL Server 2005.  I'll correct it.

Answer (score 7):

```
(DATEPART(HOUR,GETDATE()) * 60) + DATEPART(MINUTE,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Personally I find this version easier to understand than the DATEDIFF calculations.

Answer (score 2):

This query will return the number of minutes past midnight.

```
declare @now datetime = getdate()
declare @midnight datetime = CAST( FLOOR( CAST( @now AS FLOAT ) ) AS DATETIME )
select datediff(mi, @midnight,@now)
```

The code

```
CAST( FLOOR( CAST( "yourDateTimeHere" AS FLOAT ) ) AS DATETIME )
```

converts any datetime to midnight.  Use the datediff with the "mi" function to get the number of minutes past midnight.

Use books online for more date and time math

Comment: The term 'midnight' may be misleading here, since you might think that to mean `23:59:59`, but instead it's `00:00:00`. i.e. If you want to perform some calculation based on 'midnight' of `Dec 31 2016`, you would likely expect `Dec 31 11:59:59`, or perhaps `Jan 01 2017 00:00:00`, but probably not `Dec 31 00:00:00`, which is what your code above would give you.

Comment: I think that the term 'midnight' in terms of coding and 24-hour/military time is pretty clear. 00:00:00 is always the start of a new day, so if you were to say 'Midnight of Dec 31 2016' it should ALWAYS mean 2016/12/31 00:00:00.Even with a 12 hour clock and AM/PM designators, 12:00:00 AM is midnight, and it is designated as morning by the AM, it's just that it starts at 12 which is misleading.