# sql server 2005 convert time to minutes

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have a few date time functions within my database, but I need to add one that takes the time portion of a datetime field and then converts the time into minutes

I have a function that get the minutes between two times, but not just the minutes of a single time.

```
 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_MinutesBetween]
 ( @fStart datetime, @fEnd datetime )
 RETURNS int
 AS
 BEGIN
 RETURN DateDiff(minute, @fStart, @fEnd)
```

and another one that gets just the time portion

```
 ALTER function [dbo].[fn_ReturnTimeOnly]
 (@DateTime smallDateTime)
 returns nvarchar(50)
as
begin
  Return substring(cast(@DateTime as varchar),12,len(@DateTime))

end
```

How can I just get the minutes of the time.  Like 1:00 am would be 60, 2:00 am would be 120
12:00 pm would be 720  etc.

Thanks

Comment: The following post has answers that show how to calculate **Minutes Since Midnight** in `SQL-SERVER 2005`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536330/datetime-to-totalminute-in-sql

Comment: I tried converting it to my situation but the results are not accurate

Comment: Actually the conversion did work, I was comparing it wrong thank you.  Post your answer so I can give you credit

Comment: If the other answer accurately solves your problem then this question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I had to modify it, so I will post to answer, just in case someone else wants to know

Comment: Why are you wanting to return nvarchar(50)?

Comment: Glad you got it to work!

Answer (score 2):

I was given a link in comments to [datetime to totalminute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536330/datetime-to-totalminute-in-sql) 
and used that to come up with a solution.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ReturnMinutesOnly]
  ( @dt smalldatetime )

RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @dt), 0), @dt)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the number of hours, cast to int, multiply by 60, get the number of mins, cast to int, add these two.

```
ALTER function [dbo].[fn_ReturnMinutesOnly]
 (@DateTime smallDateTime)
 returns INT
as
begin
        Return
            cast(substring(cast(@DateTime as varchar),13,2) as INT) * 60 +
            cast(substring(cast(@DateTime as varchar),16,2) as INT)
end
```

Comment: It doesn't give accurate time when after 12 noon.  I modified information from the link provided in comments above and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Casting to string is expensive ([I talk about the opposite scenario here, but the concept is the same](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime)). Try this instead:

```
DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME;
SET @DateTime = GETDATE();

SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @DateTime), @DateTime);
```

In your function, this would be:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[fn_ReturnTimeOnly]
(@DateTime smallDateTime)
returns INT
as
begin
  Return (SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @DateTime), @DateTime));
end
```