# Converting the column type in No Magic Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have an entity which contains a property of type TimeSpan. We have decided to changed the property from **TimeSpan** to **Int** (minutes).
My Idea now to migrate this changes as following:

Retrieving each entry from the old column(TimeSpan) and convert it to minute (Int) and add it in the new created column.

Where/what is the best approach to do that? Shall I do it in the Seed method?! I think, this is not possible because `Seed` is called after the migration is done.

The second approach in `Up()` method. Is this a good idea? Copy/Convert the column data into another column in the Up method.

```
public partial class V30 : DbMigration
{
     public override void Up()
     {

      AddColumn("dbo.Plexes", "ISingleIsValidTimeInMinutes", c => c.Int(nullable: false));

      // I NEED HERE TO TRANSFER THE DATA FROM ISingleIsValidTime TO ISingleIsValidTimeInMinutes ?!!!
      TransformISingleIsValidTimeToInt();

      DropColumn("dbo.Plexes", "ISingleIsValidTime");
     }
....
}

private void TransformISingleIsValidTimeToInt()
{
  // HERE CONVERTING LOGIC I NEED THE EXISITNG DATA FROM DBCONTEXT!!
}
```

---

```
 public class NoMagicDatabaseConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
 {

   public NoMagicDatabaseConfiguration()
   {
    this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    this.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
   }

   protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
   {
    base.Seed(context);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest (and probably quickest) way would be to run a SQL statement with the Sql method, something along the lines of :

```
public override void Up()
{
  AddColumn("dbo.Plexes", "ISingleIsValidTimeInMinutes", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
  Sql("UPDATE Plexes SET ISingleIsValidTimeInMinutes = -DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ISingleIsValidTime, 0)");
  DropColumn("dbo.Plexes", "ISingleIsValidTime");
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to solve this problem using EF alone, you could instantiate your context during the up migration between adding and removing the columns and do the work there, but if you have a lot of rows, it could take a while

Comment: but the problem the column type; Timespan --> int the type is changed; i need to do some logic by converting!! Is possible to solve this problem with EF or i need a stored procedure to change the data in the server!????

Comment: If you want to solve this problem using EF alone, you could instantiate your context during the up migration between adding and removing the columns and do the work there, but if you have a lot of rows, it could take a while.

Comment: I will keep this as last soultion for the problem; Now I'm collecting some info about MigrationOperation & I hope I can find something in this way; thanks for help.

Comment: Migrations is the way to go. You don't need C# to solve this. The sql you need is `UPDATE Plexes SET ISingleIsValidTimeInMinutes = -DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ISingleIsValidTime, 0)`

Comment: @Colin exectly this is exactly what im looking for and I have decided to do. During the migration calling a SQL command which make the convertion in the sql server. like this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980219/sql-server-2005-convert-time-to-minutes    post the answer and I will makred thanks a lot.

Comment: @TheVedge can you please update the answer i will make it as answer

Comment: @User3805967 I've updated the answer based on the comments here.