# SQL time difference store as hr and mins

Tags: sql, jdbc, db2

Hi I have a requirement to store time difference in SQL 
I will be using jdbc and DB2 for that.

e.g.
I have three tables where six columns are of interest(after performing joins)

1. ISSUES.STARTTIME
2. ISSUES.ENDTIME
3. ISSUES.HOLDSTART
4. ISSUES.HOLDSTOP
5. SLA.STATUS
6. ISSUES.TOTALTIME

What I want to achieve from a query is that it should get the difference (ISSUES.STARTTIME (ISSUES.HOLDSTART - ISSUES.HOLDSTOP)- ISSUES.ENDTIME) and store that difference as x hr: x m: zs or as a ISSUES.TOTALTIME field (e.g 3.5 = 3hr 30 m)

What I have come so far is

```
SELECT ISSUES.ISSUESID, ISSUES.STARTTIME, ISSUES.ENDTIME, ISSUES.HOLDSTART, ISSUES.HOLDSTOP,  
SLARULES.ALLOWEDTIME,
(DAYS(ISSUES.ENDTIME) - DAYS(ISSUES.STARTTIME)) * 86400 + (MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(ISSUES.ENDTIME) - 
MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(ISSUES.STARTTIME)) as DIFFSECONDSSTARTSTOP

from ISSUES 
inner join SLA
on ISSUES.ISSUESID = SLA.ISSUESID
join SLARULES on
(SLARULES.COMPANYNAME = ISSUES.COMPANYNAME and SLARULES.TTSEVERITY = ISSUES.TTSEVERITY)
```

If I try writing a pseudo code

1. If `ISSUES.STARTTIME` and `ISSUES.ENDTIME` are not null and `ISSUES.HOLDSTART , ISSUES.HOLDSSTOP` are null
   `ISSUES.STARTTIME - ISSUES.ENDTIME < SLARULES.ALLOWEDTIME` then set `ISSUES.TOTALTIME` as their difference as x hr: y m: z s (or as Duation e.g 3.5 for 3h 30 mins) and `SLA.STATUS = 'GOOD'`
2. If holds are not null
   `ISSUES.STARTTIME - (ISSUES.HOLDSTART - ISSUES.HOLDSTOP) - ISSUES.ENDTIME < SLARULES.ALLOWEDTIME` then set `ISSUES.TOTALTIME` as their difference as x hr: y m: z s and `SLA.STATUS = 'GOOD'`
3. If `ISSUES.STARTTIME, ISSUES.HOLDSTART is not null` and `ISSUES.HOLDSTOP is null`
   `ISSUES.STARTTIME - ISSUES.HOLDSTART < SLARULES.ALLOWEDTIME` then set `ISSUES.TOTALTIME` as their difference as x hr: y m: z s and `SLA.STATUS = 'GOOD'`
4. If `ISSUES.STARTTIME` is not null and `ISSUES.HOLDSTART, ISSUES.HOLDSTOP, ISSUES.ENDTIME` are null
   then
   `ISSUES.STARTTIME - currTime < SLARULES.ALLOWEDTIME` then set `ISSUES.TOTALTIME` as their difference as x hr: y m: z s and `SLA.STATUS = 'GOOD'`

I can do it via Java but is it possible via SQL queries only?

Comment: Baby steps.  First get the datediff in minutes or seconds or whatever maximum precision you need.  Then use division and the modulus operator to build the various strings you need.  Finally do your case construct.

Comment: Use datediff to get values in minutes do your operation and compare with the expected value, have a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536330/datetime-to-totalminute-in-sql